# Unable to add Root and Intermediate Certificate to Keystore

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, keystore, root-certificate

I have problems with appending the root and intermediate certificate to my SSL certificate. Please see below the steps.

1. Create Java keystore named **jira.corp.net.jks** with Self signed certificate **jira.corp.net**
2. Create a CSR to get CA signed certificate for **jira.corp.net**
3. Received CA signed certificate and imported **jira.corp.net** into **jira.corp.net.jks** via Import Reply option in Keystore Explorer
4. Appended intermediate and root certificate

The above steps works perfectly fine. Now, since my application requires the signed certificate in a different keystore **cacerts**, I imported the signed certificate. But now I don't get option to append the intermediate and root certificate. Because of this I get the below error,

> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target

I understand that since the certificate request was created in a different keystore, the append option is not available. But how do I import the root and intermediate certificate in this case?

I have checked many blogs but couldn't make it work. If someone has knowledge on how to fix, please suggest.

Thanks!

Comment: You do not add your signed certificate in the `cacerts`, you need to add the CA cert to it using the `keytool -importcert` command. If you are using KeyStore-Explorer, there is a shortcut option to open the cacerts file, I think it is called 'File > Open Special', and in it you import the CA cert using 'Add trusted cert'.

Comment: @always_a_rookie thanks for your response. When I say signed certificate, it is provided by CA authority only. The problem is I can add only the underlying certificate but not the intermediate and root certificates. I do not get the option to append the CA certificate.

Comment: You perform 'appending the CA certificate' when you add the signed cert from the CA to your original keystore, which you already did in point 3 and 4. Since you are now trying to add the CA cert to the `cacerts`, you need to **trust it**, not append it. Look for the option 'Add trusted cert' once you open the cacerts file in the KeyStore-Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i usually generated the root CA with openssl and never worked importing that into the cacerts with keytools. You can instead generate it with this application i made out of desperation (it's a Java 11 app):

https://github.com/kendarorg/JavaCaCertGenerator

Its only purpose is to replace the generation of the private key and the root certificate, in a form "fit" for cacerts. From there you can produce the various certificates for the addresses and import the root CA inside the default cacert